# variations with repetition of words

Tags: java

how would I code variation with repetitions where the value is String, not char?
using this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LinkedList<char[]> items = new LinkedList<char[]>();
        char[] item = new char[3];
        char[] input = {'A', 'B'};



        for (char[] rep : items) {
            System.out.println(rep);
        }
         rep(items, input, item, 0);
    }

    private static void rep(LinkedList<char[]> reps, char[] input, char[] item, int count){
        if (count < item.length){
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                item[count] = input[i];
                rep(reps, input, item, count+1);
            }
        }else{
            reps.add(item.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "variations with repetition of words"? Could you show us some sample output?

Comment: the output for that question is:[AAA
AAB
ABA
ABB
BAA
BAB
BBA
BBB
] 
for example the values of input is: [john, paul]
from that, i want to know its combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want, so I just took your code, changer `char` to `String` and adapted the print loop:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LinkedList<String[]> items = new LinkedList<String[]>();
        String[] item = new String[3];
        String[] input = {"john", "paul"};

        rep(items, input, item, 0);

        for (String[] rep : items) {
            for (String str : rep)
                System.out.print(str+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
         rep(items, input, item, 0);
    }

    private static void rep(LinkedList<String[]> reps, String[] input, String[] item, int count){
        if (count < item.length){
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                item[count] = input[i];
                rep(reps, input, item, count+1);
            }
        }else{
            reps.add(item.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
john john john 
john john paul 
john paul john 
john paul paul 
paul john john 
paul john paul 
paul paul john 
paul paul paul
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: how can i remove one value of those who has same values?
for example, the [john john paul] and [paul john john], [paul john john] must be removed.